# Envelope of a signal regarding shifts

Tags: fft, envelope

Assume I have a Ricker wavelet. I can compute the envelope of this wavelet as shown below:

[image]

This is the normal condition we usually see.

However, if I shift the Ricker wavelet to be wholly negative, and then I compute its envelope. A confusing phenomenon happens that the envelope looks like the opposite of the original wavelet:

[image]

Furthermore, if I shift the Ricker wavelet to be wholly positive, and compute its envelope. You can see the envelope is almost the same as the original wavelet:

[image]

Does anybody know the mathematical explanation behind these phenomena?

And how can we avoid the latter two cases? Remove the mean value of the wavelet to force it having zero mean?

Comment: I was told there wouldn't be any math...

Comment: You mean no math reason behind it? @ScottHunter

Comment: Most likely meant to say that as a programming Q&A site, the expectation is for questions to be about programming. It may involve *some* maths along the way, but your question is all about maths, without any code. Why a specific library call (potentially mathematically related) does not fit your expectation and/or hand calculated results, or how to use a specific library to achieve your desired mathematical outcome might be more on topic. I suspect you are using some library to compute those envelopes. You might consider rephrasing your question accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are working with Python with the Scipy module:

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
points = 100
a = 4.0
myricker = signal.ricker(points, a)
```

The **envelope** is typically computed as the absolute value of the **analytic signal**, which is the **Hilbert transform** of the original signal:

```
analytic_signal = signal.hilbert(myricker)
amplitude_envelope = np.abs(analytic_signal)
```

The analytic signal is a **complex quantity**.
In order to understand the behavior of envelope, try plotting its real and imaginary parts:

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(2, sharey=True)
fig.suptitle('')
ax1.plot(myricker, label='myricker')
ax1.plot(amplitude_envelope, label='envelope')
ax1.legend()
ax2.plot(np.real(analytic_signal), label='real')
ax2.plot(np.imag(analytic_signal), color='black', label='imaginary')
ax2.legend()
```

This is what you should get:

[image]

The real part of the analytic signal is identical to the original signal. The imaginary part is often referred to as the Hilbert transform itself.

Now if you shift your original ricker upwards by adding a small constant value (*e.g.* 0.2), the real part of the signal will be shifted accordingly, but the imaginary part will remain the same and therefore its contribution to the envelope will be smaller:

[image]

**As you increase the shift, the contribution of the imaginary part to the envelope becomes smaller and smaller.** Here for a shift of 1, it is so small that the envelope looks very close to the original ricker wavelet:

[image]